# TypeError ... not JSON serializable in Django with no reference to my code in the traceback

Tags: python, json, django, session-variables

Notice that my code is not listed. It is all libraries.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 59, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 82, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 69, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 94, in encode
    return signing.dumps(
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 150, in dumps
    return TimestampSigner(key, salt=salt).sign_object(
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 228, in sign_object
    data = serializer().dumps(obj)
  File "/root/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 125, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(",", ":")).encode("latin-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
    return cls(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

Exception Type: TypeError at /financialreconciliation/
Exception Value: Object of type AllCompany is not JSON serializable
```

I knew the offending view via the URL. I did a binary search in the view to try
and find the line where it occurred using print statements but I did not find it.
I got all the way to the return with print statements and they all showed.

Then I did a search using return HttpResponse() and I finally tracked down the
problem being::

```
request.session['variance_dict'] = variance_dict
```

And indeed, the dictionary had AllCompany object in it.

I am still learning the control portion of Model–View–Controller so I didn't
realize that the update to the dictionary would not happen until a return. This
may also be a python issue. I'm not sure which caused it. However, I though others might be in my spot and this might help them.

Comment: I have used `SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'` in settings.py to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For now, my solution is to not put model objects in the session. However, there may be a way to do it or a better solution so I'm hoping others will give a fuller answer/explanation.

Comment: Please don't write your temporary solution as an answer to your question. Instead, put it in the body of your question.